# Derivative of functions of several variables

Tags: analysis

From the definition of derivative of a function $f:\Bbb{R}^m \to\Bbb{R}^n$,how do I conclude that $f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+r(h)$ where $|r(h)|/h$ tends to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$?
I can't to do this. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just define $r(h)$ as $f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$ and apply the definition.